# Find sum of rows and column values through SAS

Tags: sas

I want the dataset like it is below:

[image]

From a dataset that does not have grand total row and column and the rest is same like the dataset in image.

Comment: Hi Mangoman, please do not post links in questions particularly for data.  Data should be included as text.  Further, this is not a code-generating service; you're welcome to ask questions about how to write code or help with your code, but you should provide what you've done so far and a more specific question.

Comment: i did wrote a code for bringing the dataset in the shown form from the raw data.I was not getting a clue how to find sum of columns and rows so i asked. i wanted the question to be short, simple and in understandable form so asked like this. I am not looking for code generating service.

Comment: This looks like a job for `Proc Tabulate`

Comment: @mangoman Please read the [FAQ] and the [help] for more information about writing a good question.  Fundamentally, if you are asking for help with code like this, you need to at minimum provide example data _in plain text_, and code showing what you've done so far, to help us better answer your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Some dummy data:

```
data input ;
  array M(5) M201402,M201404,M201405,M210406,201409 ;
  do desc='ABCD','EFGH' ;
    do i=1 to 5 ;
      M(i)=int(ranuni(1))*100 ;
       output ;
      end ;
  end ;
run
```

Generate grand total column plus grand total row:

```
data output ;
  set input end=eof;
  array M(*) M2014: ;
  array F(*) _temporary_ ;

  * Create grand total column ;  
  grand_total=sum(of m(*)) ;
  output ;

  * Output grand total row ;
  if eof then do ;
    do i=1 to dim(m) ;  
      M(i)=F(i) ;
     end ;
     output ;
  end ;
run ;
```